# CSS - unable to apply style to one element when hover over another

Tags: css

I have a box with a background, which is dimmed when hovered on. There is also a text, which is uncolored (transparent color), I'm trying to set its color to white when parent element is hovered on.
I know this should work:

```
#someDiv:hover > .someClass {
  color: white;
}
```

But in my code it doesn't. Can anyone point me to the mistake?
jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/za1pg6ws/).

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="box" style="background:url('http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/34000000/Sandor-Clegane-sandor-clegane-34035068-960-640.jpg')">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="hashContainer"><span class="tru">123</span></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .box {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 300px;
      margin: 40px;
      height: 300px;
      background-size: cover;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .hashContainer {
      pointer-events: none;
      position: relative;
      top: 22%;
    }

    #overlay {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      position: absolute;
    }

    #overlay:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      height: inherit;
      width: inherit;
      opacity: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      transition: all 1s;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }

    #overlay:hover:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .tru {
      font-size: 70px;
      color: transparent;
      font-weight: 900;
      transition: all 1s;
    }

    /*  not working  */
    #overlay:hover > .tru {
      color: white;
    }

   /*  not working  */
  .box > .tru {
      color: white;
    }
```

In my case, I'm trying to apply color change to the `tru` class span, while `box` \ `overlay` `div`s are hovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`#overlay`] is a sibling of[`+`] [`.hashcontainer` and `.hashcontainer`] the parent of[`>`] [`.tru`]

**CSS**

```
#overlay:hover + .hashContainer > .tru {
      color: white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
        <div id="overlay"></div><!----------------[#overlay isn't a parent of .hashContainer but an actual sibling]-->
        <div class="hashContainer"><!-------------[.hashContainer is the parent of .tru]-->
            <span class="tru">123</span>
        </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/H2Up3Y2YD6fl5uiwQky4?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, sir. For a *Game of Thrones* fan I'm happy to oblige. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following HTML document:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.someClass:hover {  //mention in this manner
  background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="id1" class="someClass" >
<h1 id="id2"  > HELLO MAN </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works. Color changes to blue when you hover over `<div>`.